# Why bracket create different answer?

Tags: python

From visual point of view the difference in `(0 - 32) * 5 / 9` and `(0 - 32) * (5 / 9)` are just brackets but I  get -18 for one and 0 for other.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Comment: i am not sure if what confuses you is the order of the operations or the integer division

Comment: In Python 3 both expressions will give you the same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a combination of the fact that in python without the division import (see below), a division of two integer numbers is always truncated to an integer and the order of operation.

> (0 - 32) * 5 / 9

```
0 - 32 = -32
-32 * 5 = -160
-160 / 9 = - 18
```

> (0 - 32) * (5 / 9)

```
0 - 32 = - 32
5 / 9 = 0
- 32 * 0 = 0
```

you should put `from __future__ import division`, on top of your python file
then divisions are not integer divisions.